# How to get type from some assembly?

Tags: c#, .net

say I have an assembly call B, inside B, there is a type called C

How to retrieve the type from C inside B.

Type.GetType seems can only get the type from the current or system assemblies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the b assembly:

```
bAssembly.GetType(ctype)
```

the `ctype` needs to be a string with `Namespace` + `TypeName`

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
assemblyB.GetType(typeName);
```

you can inspect all assemblies in your domain:

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

or target a speficic one

Answer (score 0):

It is late but posting this as alternate way to do it.

```
Type type = Type.GetType("[Namespace].[ClassName], [AssemblyName]");
```